# <b> within <pre> not visible on mobile and windows; although fonts are present

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, design, markdown-rendering

Within `<pre>`, the tag `<b>` is visually ignored on the mobile version and on some Window-versions.

For reproduction read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14242682/772868). It contains many annotated programs ([failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice)).  Like:

```
?- phrase(a,X),false,length(X,Y),Y<4.
**LOOPS**
```

Here, the **`false`** should be bold. And the part right to it should be <s>striked through</s>.

Then, click on "mobile" to switch to the mobile version. In the mobile version downmarked bold tt annotations are still present, like **`false`**, but all bold is gone from the `<pre>` environments.

---

[image: Red: Missing bold. Green: Bold is present]

---

<sub>Just as a side remark: the request for *further* markup in `<pre>` has been refused on the grounds that real programs do not posses such annotation either. But in this case here a program is annotated to explain properties of the program.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix is on dev now. It will be in the next pro build.